# IP address changes "automagically" for Default Web Site in IIS

Tags: web-services, iis, iis-6

I am having a really weird issue with IIS on one of our servers. Occasionally it seems to change the IP address from (All Unassigned) to 127.0.0.1, causing everything that uses our web service to fail. Does IIS log the configuration changes somewhere? Did anyone have similar experiences? Many people have access to this server, so despite they claim they haven't touched it I suspect human intervention here, I just need a way to track it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this happens, but I propose some workarounds:

- Create a new web with the same parameters and disable (stop) the old one. See if it still happens
- Assign a fixed (local) IP address instead of "All unassigned" and see what happens.

Is there a third-party IIS component / ISAPI extension which could interfer with your setup?

You could also check the timestamp of the [MetaBase.xml](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779862.aspx) (IIS 6) file (or MetaBase.bin in Windows Server 2000's IIS 5 -C:\WINNT\system32\inetsrv) to see when it was  manipulated.

Here is an interesting article: [Enabling Metabase Auditing in IIS 6.0 (Windows 2003 with Service Pack 1)](http://www.adopenstatic.com/faq/IISMetabaseAuditing.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Where can I find MetaBase.bin?

Comment: MetaBase.bin should be in the C:\WINNT\system32\inetsrv directory.

Comment: Looks like MetaBase.xml is that file that contains all the settings in my case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I was thinking you wrote "IIS 5"... Sure it's MetaBase.xml in Windows Server 2003 / IIS 6.0+ I'll update my answer...

Comment: I added an interesting link to an article which shows how to enable MetaBase auditing. So you should be able to track down the changes in the event log.